# Rails - Change default value on alternate new data columns

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database

this is a Rails 4 + MySQL, but perhaps a general logic question. I did not find even a related topic to this (only Frontend A/B testing), so apologies if there is somehow a related question.

I would like to do an A/B test *but* with **persistent data**.

Consider a new user registration, where one of the columns (let's call it `test`) in the table is a boolean and each new registration **saves** a **different** boolean state to the new DB row on the user's table on each new user registration.

User 1 registers -> `test` value in User1 row is `false`

User 2 registers -> `test` value in User2 row is `true`

User 3 registers -> `test` value in User3 row is `false`

User 4 registers -> `test` value in User4 row is `true`

And so on...

Is there a way to achieve this in Rails? Or is this a DB/MySQL issue?

Thanks!

Comment: In the User, `before_create { self.test = !User.order(:id).last&.test.present? }` should do the trick (First ever created user would end up with `true`, second with `false`, third with `true`, and so on). Otherwise, a MySQL trigger before `INSERT` statements could do the exact same thing, but on the DB level

Comment: @MrYoshiji that sounds great, thanks a lot! Please submit it as an answer so that I can approve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see 2 options: use Rails' callback `before_create` (or `before_validation`) or use a MySQL `trigger` before `INSERT`.

**Rails Callback:**

```
before_create do
  self.test = !User.order(:id).last&.test.present?
end
```